# Visual Studio Code - Open debugging in a new Chrome tab

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

For now, when I want to debug my code, Visual Studio opens a new instance of Chrome. I would prefer Visual Studio open a new tab of my current Chrome instance.

I've try to edit the lauch.json file with this, but he doesn't work :

`"configurations": [
    {
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "attach",
      "name": "Attach to Chrome",
      "url": "http://localhost:3000",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    },
  ]`

Do you have an idea ? Thanks you !

**Edit:** My Visual Studio Code is in version 1.21.1

Comment: Hi Jon, did you find out how to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

I actually just asked the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63287059/vs-code-debugger-for-chrome-open-tab-in-existing-chrome-instance-instead-of) - this works for me ([source](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-chrome-debug/issues/1005)):

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost:3000",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "userDataDir": false,
        },
    ]
}
```