# Unable to login to web app when using VSCode Chrome Debugger

Tags: javascript, vue.js, visual-studio-code, google-chrome-devtools

When I start a debugging session on VSCode, it opens a new Chrome window and loads my web app. My web app requires the user to sign-in via Google to use.

When I try to sign in, I get an error saying "This browser or app may not be secure". There is no option that allows me to bypass this and sign in. Does anyone know a way around this?

Comment: where is the error thrown exactly?

Comment: Related post, with working answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63287059/vs-code-debugger-for-chrome-open-tab-in-existing-chrome-instance-instead-of/76326993

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logged into the correct google account turning on "Less secure app access" on https://myaccount.google.com/security should work

From google support: https://support.google.com/accounts/thread/22873505?msgid=24501976

Comment: The "Less secure apps" feature appears to be gone as of May 30, 2022: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255

Answer (score 4):

There is a Bug filed with Chrome Team.
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1173641

Also here's the issue on github of VS Code
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-js-debug/issues/918

As of now (9th Jan 2022), the only solution is to use other browser or use different way of Debugging.

Answer (score 0):

as @adarsh-madrecha looks like there is something in chrome / chromium --remote-debugging-pipe that causes this, the other option is to use --remote-debugging-port, in my case it is working.

I found in [vscode-js-debug](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-js-debug/blob/main/OPTIONS.md) doc how to do this. You can specify the port attribute in your launch configuration for visual studio code.

> port
> Port for the browser to listen on. Defaults to "0", which will cause the browser to be debugged via pipes, which is generally more secure and should be chosen unless you need to attach to the browser from another tool.
>
> Default value:
> 0

I just selected one random port (9876) and worked for me, so this is how my launch.json file looks like:

```
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
      "url": "http://localhost:5500",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "port": 9876
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Close all the chrome instances

In powershell:

```
stop-process -name chrome
```

Add `"userDataDir": false` to your launch.json

Hit F5.

My launch.json

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost:3000",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/src",
            "userDataDir": false
        }
    ]
}
```

If you are lazy and don't force close all chrome instances you receive error: "Unable to attach to browser"